# Would have+ed instead of have+ed?

Tags: grammar, tense

I've seen '' Would have + ed '' in the sense of have + ed or just ed. why ? for example :

Context : '' **Z** had no house because he's poor but now he has a house. **A** and **B** his friends are wondering how he did to buy it. ''

**A** to **B**: According to what **C** said **V** would have helped **Z** to buy his house. What do you think?

**B** to **A**: I don't think **V** (have) helped **Z** buy his house..

Comment: This is confusing, is V a person or an object? Can you put in names instead of letters please?

Comment: V is a person .

Comment: "how he did to buy it" is wrong. It probably should be "how he bought it", or if you must "how he did buy it".

Answer (score 0):

**This is the conditional perfect tense**

> The conditional perfect is a grammatical construction that combines the conditional mood with perfect aspect. A typical example is the English *would have written*

In your example, it is "According to what **C** said **V** would have helped **Z** to buy his house."

This means that **V** did not help **Z**, but if they had known/been available to help, they *would have* done it.

This specific example is often shortened to *Would've*.

Comment: Note that the sentence in the question begins **I don't think...**. this indicates that V would**not**,  in the opinion of B, have helped Z even if the opportunity arose.

Comment: @JavaLatte I was referring to the line above that

Comment: No A believe that V helped Z because C said so, And he's questioning B for his opinion if he thinks that V really  did so.

Comment: @VeryBadAtEnglish is the example you gave from a book, or did you just write it?

Comment: I just wrote based on what I remember. cause right now I don't have any real example